# Gray border when hiding tabitems and border

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, tabcontrol

I have a fairly standard TabControl (no controltemplates). When there is only one tab the tab is hidden with following trigger:

```
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

The border of TabControl is also removed with the following trigger:

```
            <TabControl.Style>
                <Style TargetType="TabControl">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,1,0,0"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Items.Count, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="1">
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,0"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.Style>
```

This works well except for one thing. The TabItems are gone and the border also. BUT, there is still a light gray border (about 2px wide) surrounding the ContentPresenter (see screenshot). I have tried various solutions (controltemplate modifications) that i've found but they have all caused various other issues. How do i get rid of this border?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0):

The border is exactly the border of the `TabControl`. You can also add a Style trigger for the TabControl to remove the border (by setting `BorderThickness` to `0`):

```
<TabControl.Style>
      <Style TargetType="TabControl">
         <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                   Path=Items.Count}" Value="1">
               <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            </DataTrigger>                
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</TabControl.Style>
```

Comment: That's what i thought to begin with, but no. this has nothing to do with the BorderThickness property of TabControl. This is some sort of border rendered inside the border you're talking about. I will edit my question to clarify this.

Comment: @sundown your screenshot does not show me anything (sorry). Maybe it's not clear. Please try setting the `BorderBrush` of the TabControl to something distinct (such as the Red color), then the border you mean may be distinct (with some zooming in). At least the screenshot then will be more helpful in showing what the problem is.

Comment: The gray border in the screenshot is clearly visible on my monitor. Maybe the problem is your monitor settings, because it's a very light gray. the border is just above the black arrow that i added to the screenshot.

To sum it up: I have removed the border on the tabcontrol. But there seems to be some sort of "dropshadow effect" left.

Comment: @sundown when using my code, that border is still shown?

Comment: Yes, the lightgray 2px border is still visible. I should also add that the background in the contentpresenter is white, not the standard gray. If the background was the standard gray color then the border maybe wouldn't be visible.

Comment: @sundown Not sure what it is, on my side using the code above will hide all the border. Maybe your TabItem has some border. So try adding trigger for the TabItem instead.

Comment: The border surrounds the whole contentpresenter. so i dont think this is a tabitem border

Comment: Anyway it must be a problem specific to the whole code in your project. This is hard to remotely debug. You should try finding out what exactly it is and simply hide it (or make it transparent) when needed.

Comment: This is strictly related to the TabControl. I'm beginning to think that it's the border x:Name="Border" in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754137.aspx